# Como passar o Model para o controller via JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

É possível passar o Model preenchido para o controller via jquery, sem ter que criar uma variavel e ir populando ela com todos campos?

Exemplo:

tenho um modal popup que abre uma partialview com varios campos. nessa view eu tenho o model:

```
@model Contato
```

os campos preenchem o model:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefone)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Documento)
```

Clico no botão para fechar o model

```
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                data-dismiss="modal" id="btnSaveContato">
            Close
        </button>
    </div>
```

Ai quero passar o model todo para o controller quando fechar o popup

```
<script>
    $('#btnSaveContato').on('click', function () {
        var model = @model???
    });
</script>
```

sem ter que fazer isso

```
var model = {
 Nome = campo.val(),
 Email = campo.val(),
 Telefone = campo.val(),
 Endereco = campo.val(),
 Documento = campo.val(),
}
```

É possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola, Guilherme não sei se isso pode lhe ajudar, mas eu faço da seguinte maneira:

**PS: não tenho certeza se é a forma correta, porem me atendeu bem.**

Criei uma função javascript:

```
function ChamarAjax(Pagina, Data = null, DivRecebedor = null) {
    // verifico se foi passado algum valor para o json
    if (typeof (Data) == "undefined" && Data == null) {

        // se for vazio gero um valor aleatorio qualquer
        Data = { nome: "nome" }

    }
    // função pace tracker que mostra um loading no topo da pagina
    Pace.track(function () {

        // chamo o ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: Pagina,
            /// transformo os valores do form no formato json e envio via post

            data: JSON.stringify(Data),

            // caso tenha algum sucesso ele pega o retorno do controller
            success: function (data) {

                // verifico se esse campo vai atualizar algum div ou pagina completa.
                if (typeof (DivRecebedor) !== "undefined" && DivRecebedor !== null) {
                    $("#" + DivRecebedor).html(data);
                } else {

                    // redireciono para o controller de resposta do controller json
                    window.location.replace(data);
                }

            },

           // se retornar algum erro mostra na tela 
            error: function (a, jqXHR, exception) {
                jAlert(Data, "ERRO");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Esse script vai executar efetuar um post via json para meu controller.
Chamando essa função pelo click do jquery:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#botaoLogarEstoque', function () {
    var campo1 = $("#campo01").val();
    var campo2 = $("#campo02").val();
    var campo3 = $("#campo03").val();
    var campo4 = $("#campo04").val();
    var campo5 = $("#campo05").val();

         // pego os valores para virar um json dentro da função chamarajax
        data = {
              "campo01" = campo01,
              "campo02" = campo02,
              "campo03" = campo03,
              "campo04" = campo04,
              "campo05" = campo05
        }
        console.log(data);

       // aqui eu chamo meu controller
       ChamarAjax("/Login/AcessoSistema", data, null);

    });
```

No controller eu faço dessa forma:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AcessoSistema(int campo01,
                                          int campo02,
                                          int campo03,
                                          int campo04,
                                          int campo05)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            // trato os dados recebidos via ajax-json
            // campo01....campo05.

            // aqui e o retorno do json para o controller que vai mostrar a view.
            return Json("/Home/Index");
        }
```